# linking to google analytics

Tags: javascript, .net, google-analytics

We want to add google analytics a fairly large .NET web site.  The site uses several master pages (4 or 5) and so I was going to just paste the requisite javascript into each master page.

```
<script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[

      var gaJsHost = (("https:" == document.location.protocol) ? "https://ssl." : "http://www.");
      document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src='" + gaJsHost + "google-analytics.com/ga.js' type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E"));
    //]]></script>
<script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[

      try {
      var pageTracker = _gat._getTracker("UA-xxxxxx-x");
      pageTracker._trackPageview();
      } catch(err) {}
    //]]></script>
```

Is there a better way to encapsulate this?  Just linking to an external js file would not do the trick due to the `<![CDATA`.  We could also create a static method and dump it into an asp:literal.  Is there a more elegant solution?

Comment: @fernandopasik If you're going to mass-add the [tag:google-analytics] tag to posts, at least fix other issues with them: as they stand, your edits are too minor.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to migrate the code into an *.ascx web control. You centralize the code in one place (in case it changes) and you can easily add it to whatever pages you need.